# How to run python script in directory in Cron (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, cron, automation, raspberry-pi

I just started using Cron to automate this one python script I have. I understand how to use all the time parameters in nano, but I'm confused with how you would run the script. Normally just to run it right from the console, I would do:

```
cd /pi/home/weather/Adafruit_Python_BMP/examples
```

and then from there I would run the script with:

```
python weatherFINAL.py
```

Now that I'm trying to automate this in Cron, I can't do the multiple commands to cd into the directory, and then run the program. I know this is probably a really easy problem to fix, but I've been stuck on this for a while. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple:

1. Write a shebang line on the top of your script in order to make it executable:

   !/usr/bin/env python
2. Make sure you can execute that script with chmod command:

   $ chmod +x
3. Programn a crontab task with contrab command:

   $contrab -e

Comment: Just to make sure I'm executing it right, what is the right way to properly execute the cron script, or does it run automatically?

Comment: After step two you can execute it with "./" in order to do some test.
I think that's the right way to do it, using crontab editor. Once set, contrab will execute it automatically in the period of time you set it. So make sure you set it properly.

Comment: @E Rodriguez Is the "./" in the file directory to the script I'm trying to run? (If it is, where in the directory call is it?) Or is the "./" used somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. In the same directory, you can do ./myscript.py instead of python myscript.py.

If you are not, then it would be ./<path_to_script>/myscript.py